# Using nested loops in C

Tags: c, nested-loops

I'm doing an exercise in C Primer Plus 6th Edition. It says to use nested loops to produce this output
$ 
$$ 
$$$ 
$$$$ 
$$$$$

My code produces the correct output but I don't really understand why it does
Could someone explain exactly what its doing

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int CHAR = 5;
    int row;
    int qty;
    char ch;

    ch = '$';

    for(row = ROWS; row > 0; row--)
    {       
        for(qty = row ; qty <= CHAR; qty++ )
        {
            printf("%c", ch);
        }

        printf("\n");

    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug your code step by step it will help you to understand.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(row = ROWS; row > 0; row--)
```

This outer loop above create a loop where the values of `row` iterate from 5 to 1 inclusive. It runs the body of the loop once per line, for five lines.

```
for(qty = row ; qty <= CHAR; qty++ )
```

This inner above loop is similar but it iterates `qty` from `row` to `5` inclusive. Its behaviour is slightly different each time because the value of `row` is different. It runs once per character on each line.

- On the first line, `row` is `5`, so `qty` iterates from 5 to 5 (once), producing one `$`.
- On the second line, `row` is `4`, so `qty` iterates from 4 to 5 (twice), producing `$$`.
- I'll skip the third and fourth line since you should be able to work out what's going on.
- On the fifth line, `row` is `1`, so `qty` iterates from 1 to 5 (five times), producing `$$$$$`.

And that's all there is to it, really.

---

One thing I like to teach my students is how to run code in their head. Start with a sheet containing spaces for each variable (and the output in this case) and run through the code line by line, changing the variables as you go.

Here's one filled in up to the point where the outer loop is ready to run:

```
ROWS | CHAR | ch | row | qty | output
-----+------+----+-----+-----+-------
   5 |    5 |  $ |     |     |
     |      |    |     |     |
     |      |    |     |     |
     |      |    |     |     |
     |      |    |     |     |
     |      |    |     |     |
     |      |    |     |     |
     |      |    |     |     |
     |      |    |     |     |
     |      |    |     |     |
     |      |    |     |     |
```

---

Your code is a little unusual in that the counting each loop does is not necessarily intuitive. A more "logical" method may well be to run a counter from `1` to `5` for the lines and output that many characters on each line, something like:

```
for (row = 1; row <= ROWS; row++) {
    for (qty = 1 ; qty <= row; qty++ ) {
        putchar (ch);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

You'll also notice I've replaced your `printf()` calls with `putchar()`, selection of the correct output function is a particular bugbear of mine :-)

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Teacher's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators))

Answer (score 1):

Look at this piece of your code(I changed it a bit):

```
for(row = 5; row > 0; row--)
    {       
        for(qty = row ; qty <= 5; qty++ )
        {
            printf("$");
        }

        printf("\n");

    }
```

Firstly,`row` is set to 5. Then, the condition `row>0` is checked . If true the outer loop gets executed.

Secondly,`qty` is set to `row` and `qty>=5` is checked. If true, the inner loop gets executed.

Thirdly, After each iteration of the inner loop,`qty` gets incremented and After each iteration of the outer loop,`row` gets decremented.

---

In the first iteration,`row` will be 5 and `qty` will be 5 and will loop 1 time,printing 1 `$`.
 
In the second iteration,`row` will be 4 and `qty` will be 4 and will loop 2 times,printing 2 `$`.
In the third iteration,`row` will be 3 and `qty` will be 3 and will loop 3 times,printing 3 `$`.
In the forth iteration,`row` will be 2 and `qty` will be 2 and will loop 4 times,printing 4 `$`.
In the final iteration,`row` will be 1 and `qty` will be 1 and will loop 5 times,printing 5 `$`.